# Speeding up with np.select() or if else clause

Tags: python, numpy, gis, array-broadcasting

Question for Python GIS developers. I have a high density 3D point cloud with up to 73 observations per pixel. Cloud was obtained with SFM. I am fusing the DEM made from the cloud as new bands in a HSI imagerie for future analysis.

I have a numpy array representing the 8 band (n point, min z, maz z, sum z...). I need to change the value of this array based on a point cloud. Therefore, I can only work one pixel at a time making numpy vectorizing a bad idea.

Variables are:
map_z = a float with the altitude of a single cloud point above avg sea level array is the 8 band numpy array

```py
array = np.full((nbands, 2000, 3000), np.nan, dtype=OUTPUT_RASTER_DTYPE)
```

I have tried two version of the code.  A vectorized version and a Else If version.

```py
slice_arr = array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x]
slice_arr[0] = np.where(slice_arr[0] == 0, 1, slice_arr[0] + 1)
slice_arr[1] = np.select([np.isnan(slice_arr[1]) == True, slice_arr[1] > map_z], [map_z, map_z], slice_arr[1])
slice_arr[2] = np.select([np.isnan(slice_arr[2]) == True, slice_arr[2] < map_z], [map_z, map_z], slice_arr[2])
slice_arr[3] = np.where(np.isnan(slice_arr[3]) == True, map_z, slice_arr[3] + map_z)
array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x] = slice_arr
```

or

```py
slice_arr = array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x] # Take a slice of the array
if slice_arr[0] == 0:
    slice_arr[0] = 1
else:
    slice_arr[0] = slice_arr[0] + 1
if np.isnan(slice_arr[1]) == True:
    slice_arr[1] = map_z
elif slice_arr[1] > map_z:
    slice_arr[1] = map_z
else:
    pass
if np.isnan(slice_arr[2]) == True:  
    slice_arr[2] = map_z
elif slice_arr[2] < map_z:
    slice_arr[2] = map_z
else:
    pass
if np.isnan(slice_arr[3]) == True:  
    slice_arr[3] = map_z
else:
    slice_arr[3] = slice_arr[3] + map_z
array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x] = slice_arr
```

Obviously, the If else version is 4 times faster because I am operating one pixel at a time. This is because the map_z is a point cloud and I can only deal with one point at a time and this points fall on only one pixel in my array. Vectorizing should be operated on larger arrays.

Is there a way I could speed up this part of my code using numpy?
Is there a speed advantage to slicing my array (slice_arr) if the array is much bigger than (8,2000,3000)?

Comment: If you're looking at one pixel at a time, then you're wasting your time using all of numpy's fancy mechanisms.  They're designed to give you a speedup *for vectorized operations*.   So if you really need one pixel at a time, then by all means, the second one.  If you can vectorize the operations (get rid of pixel_x, pixel_y), then use the first.

Comment: Ok thank, I vectorize the next part of the code to figure out the avg and some masks and that I’d very quick.  I was hoping there could be a way to use np.where() where each condition could apply to a part of my slice.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able increase the speed of my If Else clause but putting it in a function and using numba.  This reduce the time from 2.33 min. to .42 min.!

```py
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def query_speed_up(slice_arr, map_z):

    if slice_arr[0] == 0:
        slice_arr[0] = 1
    else:
        slice_arr[0] = slice_arr[0] + 1

    # min z
    if np.isnan(slice_arr[1]) == True:  # not is
        slice_arr[1] = map_z
    elif slice_arr[1] > map_z:
        slice_arr[1] = map_z
    else:
        pass

    # max z
    if np.isnan(slice_arr[2]) == True:  # not is
        slice_arr[2] = map_z
    elif slice_arr[2] < map_z:
        slice_arr[2] = map_z
    else:
        pass

    # sum z
    if np.isnan(slice_arr[3]) == True:  # not is
        slice_arr[3] = map_z
    else:
        slice_arr[3] = slice_arr[3] + map_z

    return slice_arr

slice_arr = array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x]  # Take a slice of the array
jittest = query_speed_up(slice_arr, map_z)
array[0:4, pixel_y, pixel_x] = jittest
```